# I don't understand why my "Comparable" interface isn't working

Tags: java

I am trying to implement `comparable` in order to use the `Arrays.sort(array)` but for some reason its not finding the `compareTo` method in the super class. I am trying to compare strings FYI.

Edit: Sorry I forgot to add the error I am getting. Here it is:

```java
Employee.java:32: error: cannot find symbol     
return super.compareTo((Object)other);
            ^
symbol: method compareTo(Object)
```

Code:

```java
public abstract class Employee implements Cloneable, Comparable
{
private Name name;
private double weeklyPay;
public Employee(String first, String middle, String last, double weeklyPay)
{
    this.weeklyPay = weeklyPay;
    name = new Name(first,middle,last);
}
public Employee(String last, double weeklyPay)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.weeklyPay = weeklyPay;
    name = new Name(last);
}
public Employee(String first, String last, double weeklyPay)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.weeklyPay = weeklyPay;
    name = new Name(first,last);
}

public abstract double getWeeklyPay();

public String getFullName()
{
    return name.getFullName();
}

public int compareTo(Object other)
{
    return super.compareTo((Object)other);
}

public int compareTo(Name name)
{
    return compareTo((Object)name.getFullName());
}
```

Comment: What's not working about it? Please provide more details so that we can help you.

Comment: What is the super comparable class?

Comment: If Employee doesn't extends any class other than Object, you can't call super.compareTo, becase super refers to the Object class, and there's no compareTo method in Object.

Comment: i think the super class is `Object` as he defines his class like this `class Employee implements Cloneable, Comparable` with no `extends ...`

Comment: Okay sorry I forgot to add the error message, I just added it. Now I took out the `super.` and now its giving me a `no suitable method found for compareTo(String)` error. I am trying to compare `other.getFullName`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`java.lang.Object`, which is your superclass, does not implement `Comparable`. You should change the signature of your class to:

```
public abstract class Employee implements Cloneable, Comparable<Employee>
```

And then implement this method:

```
public int compareTo(Employee other) {
    // logic to compare here
}
```

With actual logic to do the comparison (aka, don't try and depend on some other objects implementation).

Answer (score 1):

`Comparable` is an `interface`, and it therefore has no default implementation. Your class does not extend any other `class`, which means that it is not inheriting any implementation(s) either.

`super.compareTo(...)` will always fail in this way as a result, unless you extend another class that provides an implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you really want to write different Comparators, one ofr each field you want to compare: Name, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are attempting to call `super.compareTo( Object object)` but because your class Employee does not itself extend a class, it will be looking for the compareTo method in Object and Object does not have that method. You need to actually implement the compareTo functionality within Employee.